# Keeping track of the 3 most recently visited items using sessions

Tags: php, arrays

When a user visits an item on my site, I have this code:

```
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>$page['current_item']['title'], "link"=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

which stores a record of the item and its URI in a session variable.

However, I only want to store the 3 most recently visited items.

Is there a way to do this using the `array[]` syntax? I want the max length of the array to be  3, and if it's greater than 3, the old `array[0]` would vanish, and be replaced by `array[1]`, `array[1]` would be replaced by `array[2]` etc.

Can anyone think of a nice short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_slice()` to leave just the last 3 elements :

```
$_SESSION['recent'][] = array("title"=>$page['current_item']['title'], "link"=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SESSION['recent'] = array_slice($_SESSION['recent'],-3);
```

Answer (score 2):

array_slice looks like it could do the trick (a 'substr' for arrays):

```
$_SESSION['recent'] = array_slice($_SESSION['recent'],0,3)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php